# log out after session from cyber cafe

Tags: discussion, login

After a posting session from  a publicly owned terminal, how to log out ?

Comment: You should begin by opening a Private Browsing session. Then you just close the window.

Answer (score 1):

First, click "log out" in the "Site Switcher:

[image: logout]

The page will helpfully remind you:

> If you're on a shared computer, remember to log out of your Open ID provider (Facebook, Google, Stack Exchange, etc.) as well.

Oddly, there is no link to [log out of SE Open Id](https://openid.stackexchange.com/account/logout) on that page. So here you have it.

(If that link gives you a "page not found" page, then you're already logged out)

[Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188284/259867)

---

Or, you could wipe out *all* local data from the browser: cookies, history, etc. This is what I would probably do.